# Spaghetti code, dealing with exception handling and errors?

Tags: php, design-patterns, exception, refactoring

I'm writing a wrapper for online translation services. Currently the `OnlineTranslator` class looks really ugly to me, like spaghetti code. It's because exception generation for many errors that can occur in the underline service (Bing, actually).

I'm not so good in understanding how dealing with exceptions and errors. Any change to refactor my code (who said patterns?)? How to get rid of so many `if` in the code?

```
<?php
namespace DL\AdminBundle\Service;

class OnlineTranslator
{

    private $_service;
    private $_languages;
    private $_from;
    private $_to;

    private $_ERRORS = array(
        'UNSUPPORTED_DETECTION' => "'%s' service doesn't support language
            detection. Manually call 'setFrom' to set the source language.",
        'UNSUPPORTED_FROM_LANGUAGE' => "Source language code '%s' unrecognized
            or not supported by this service.",
        'UNSUPPORTED_TO_LANGUAGE' => "Destination language code '%s'
            unrecognized or not supported by this service.",
        'MISSING_TO_LANGUAGE' => "Destination language code is missing.",
        'GENERIC_SERVICE_ERROR' => "'%s' service returned an error: %s."
    );

    function __construct(IOnlineTranslator $service)
    {

        // Imposta il servizio e la lingua sorgente su auto
        $this->_service = $service;
        $this->_from = 'auto';

        $response = $this->_service->getLanguages();

        if ($response->error)
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['GENERIC_SERVICE_ERROR'],
                $this->_service->getName(), $response->data));

        $this->_languages = $response->data;

    }

    function setFrom($languageCode)
    {

        // Controlla se la lingua è supportata
        if (!in_array($languageCode, $this->_languages))
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['UNSUPPORTED_FROM_LANGUAGE'],
                $languageCode));

        // Imposta la lingua sorgente
        $this->_from = $languageCode;

    }

    function setTo($languageCode)
    {

        // Controlla se la lingua è supportata
        if (!in_array($languageCode, $this->_languages))
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['UNSUPPORTED_TO_LANGUAGE'],
                $languageCode));

        // Imposta la lingua destinazione
        $this->_to = $languageCode;

    }

    function translate($text)
    {

        // Controlla che sia impostata la lingua di destinazione
        if (!isset($this->_to))
            throw new Exception($this->_ERRORS['MISSING_TO_LANGUAGE']);

        // Se detect è auto controlla che il servizio lo supporti
        if ('auto' == $this->_from && !$this->_service->isDetectAware())
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['UNSUPPORTED_DETECTION'],
                $this->_service->getName()));

        // Imposta la lingua sorgente chiamando il metodo detect
        $response = $this->_service->detect($text);

        if ($response->error)
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['GENERIC_SERVICE_ERROR'],
                $this->_service->getName(), $response->data));

        $this->_from = $response->data;

        // Traduci il testo chiamando il metodo translate
        $response = $this->_service->translate($text, $this->_from,
            $this->_to);

        if ($response->error)
            throw new Exception(sprintf(
                $this->_ERRORS['GENERIC_SERVICE_ERROR'],
                $this->_service->getName(), $response->data));

        return $response->data;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: @KingCrunch `if`, `if`, `if` and again `if`.

Comment: Are `if` blocks a problem for some reason?

Comment: You call that spaghetti code? I think you've never seen actual spaghetti code my friend. :) @Jared is right, there's nothing wrong with `if` blocks when you use them correctly (i.e.: when there is no other cleaner alternative), which in this case is correct. You may want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It's still in beta, but unless you have a specific question/problem, not much we can do here.

Comment: If you want to refactor nested if-statements, try to use decision tables. But, IMHO, your code not so bad.

Comment: As @netcoder alludes to, [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) is code that is very **hard** to trace what it is doing, because of backtracks, lack of visual logical flow, `goto` and other intention-obscuring techniques. This is not an example of this problem, AFAICT. It's actually not very hard at all to understand it's intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others said, it's not really spaghetti code here.  The problem is there is somewhat verbose validation and exception throwing in every function.  Validation is a [cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) so it can end up scattered all over and hinder readability.

One way to handle this is to wrap up the validation code into separate functions and try to reduce some of the verbosity and duplication.  You could also look into [PHP AOP](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/573-Current-State-of-AOP-for-PHP.html) if this is a systemic issue.  Although I have no experience with AOP, logging/error handling is often given as an example of its use.